# Social Login allows only few accounts

Tags: social-connected

Our website has the OOB social login feature and there are two Facebook accounts for testing.

Account1 - Created with a valid email & later added a valid phone number
Account2 - Created with a valid Phone number & later added an invalid email

I can login to Facebook with both the accounts by phone/email, without any issues.

The Facebook App we are using has both these accounts as administrators.

When I use social login in my site:

I can login with phone/email of Account1 without any issues.
But with Account2, the login doesn't happen with either. After clicking on FB login, it redirects to the previous page with "authResult=error_someguid" in the query string

We have a method, to prevent Sitecore from creating user accounts on social login.

**custom.config:**

```
<pipelines>
 <social.matchUser>
  <processor type="MySite.Foundation.Common.Utilities.SitecoreExtensions+MySiteSocial, MySite.Foundation.Common" patch:before="*[1]">
    <sites hint="list">
     <site>MYSITE</site>
    </sites>
  </processor>
 </social.matchUser>
</pipelines>
```

**class:**

```
public class MySiteSocial
{
  public void Process(SelectUserPipelineArgs args)
  {
    ....
    ....
    string fbid = args.AccountBasicData.Id;
    string email= args.AccountBasicData.Email;
    string name = args.AccountBasicData.FullName;
    ....
  }
}
```

When logged in with Account2 by phone/email, there is no value for `email`. 
I am unable to figure out if this is an issue at Sitecore, the FB App or the Account.

If the login to Facebook is successful with both accounts, shouldn't it also be so, when using Social login.

using Sitecore 8.0 update 5

**UPDATE:**

I read that, this happens when there is invalid data in user profile. In this case, the email in Account 2 is invalid and hence the issue.

Though Facebook allows the login even with invalid data, the Facebook App that we use on website doesn't seem to.

I would appreciate, if anyone can suggest a way to get those invalid data too, with a social login.

Comment: did you try it in two different browsers for account 1 & account 2 ?

Comment: Yes tried with different browsers

Comment: Could you Try clearing all the caches through /sitecore/admin/cache.aspx and try again.

Comment: I just did that, but I don't think it's a cache issue. Please see the "Update" in my question.